# How to store a variable so it is accessible by the entire project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, static

I have a big asp.net mvc project and i want to have some variable in all of my project's parts.
For example :

```
userid
username
companyid
companyname
```

I've used session to store it this way : a static class that named "Helper" contain this variable like this:

```
public static string _username 
{
 get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["_username"].ToString(); } 
 set { if (HttpContext.Current.Session["_username"] == null) { Http    Context.Current.Session.Add("_username", value); } else { HttpContext.Current.Session["_username"] = value; } } 
}
```

but in some views my sessions is removed with no reason
what is your best suggestion to have some variable all of project?

Comment: views?you mean cshtml file?mvc views base type is System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage;and you can custom youself

Comment: why my sessions restore to previous values?

Comment: Sessions expire in default 20 minutes. The behavior from session in asp are quite strange. The session keeps working but it has lost it value. You can check if the session has reset by using: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.IsNewSession if it's true then you know it has expired. You can use server side sessions stored in your database. It has the advantage that it doesn't expire but it has some disadvantages, do a google search and you will find out why.